# How can I convert logical clause to LEAN?

Tags: first-order-logic, lean

I have a logical clause like this:

```
exists l.(language(l) & exists n.(name(n) & :op1(n,"English") & :name(l,n)))
```

which corresponds to the expression: "language is English"

The clause consists of the variables (l,n), predicates (language, name, op1) and constants ("English"). Each variable is assigned to its corresponding class first (l is assigned to "language" and n is assigned to "name") then the instance of a class is used for further inference (:op1 is a predicate assigning the constant "English" to the instance of the class "language". Or it can be considered as a property of a class "language").

Is there a way to convert this into LEAN code?

Comment: It is possible but very unnatural to express this FOL clause directly in lean. What is "language is English" supposed to mean here? Is "language" a property of a structure and "english" is the value assigned to that property? Is "english" a string or an enumerated type? What is the role of the "name" type as intermediary between these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways you might map this into Lean, and it can depend greatly on what you're wanting to model exactly.  In any case, here's one possibility.

Lean uses type theory, and one difference between type theory and first-order logic is that quantification is always bounded by a type, rather than there being a universal domain of discourse.  Maybe the most idiomatic way to write this is as

```
namespace lang_ex

inductive language
| english

def name : language → string
| language.english := "English"

end lang_ex
```

This defines a new type called `language` that has one inhabitant called `language.english`, and it defines a function `name` that takes something with type `language` and yields a `string` (standing in for your `name` class).  The rule for the function is that its value when given `language.english` is "English".

What these directives do, more or less, is define the following axioms:

```
namespace lang_ex

constant language : Type
constant language.english : language
constant name : language → string
axiom name_english : name language.english = "English"

end lang_ex
```

(There's no difference between `constant` and `axiom` -- they both introduce things axiomatically.)  In Lean, function application syntax is by juxtaposition, so `name language.english` rather than `name(language.english)`.

---

Here's an unidiomatic way to write it, following your clause as closely as possible:

```
namespace lang_ex

constant univ : Type
constant is_language : univ → Prop
constant is_name : univ → Prop
constant op1 : univ → string → Prop
constant name : univ → univ → Prop

axiom clause :
  ∃ (l : univ), is_language l ∧
    ∃ (n : univ), is_name n ∧ op1 n "English" ∧ name l n

end lang_ex
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the extended answer. My idea is to be able to translate natural language into logical axioms and reuse them for inference. For example, when I ask a question "what language is it?" I should be able to find an answer based on the axioms which was added previously. Which one of your example methods can do it the best way? Can you write a sample code in Lean which would be able to extract an answer from the existing axiom?

Comment: @user2222943 While you could probably use Lean for what you're talking about, one thing to know is that it's meant to be an *interactive theorem prover*, not an *automated theorem prover*. It does have many helpful automations for writing proofs, but you probably shouldn't think of Lean as giving you a queryable knowledge base.  Have you already considered more classic approaches like using Prolog?